# how to calculate natural logarithm using pandasql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandasql

I was trying to run the following query by using pandasql:

```
query='SELECT LOG(A) FROM table1'
output=pandasql.sqldf(query,globals())
```

But I got this error: 'no such function: LOG'. So, I want to know how can I calculate the natural algorithm in sqlite3. How can I implement this function?

Comment: https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/67 Might help...